# Определить на jQuery, обычный был клик по елементу или двойной?

Tags: jquery

Добрый день?

Можно ли в jQuery каким-то образом определить, произвелся ли по одному и тому же элементу обычный клик левой мыши или двойной клик?

Например, имеем

```
<div id="here">Вот на меня нажимают</div>
```

Пытался играться как-то через **if**, но ничего не вышло.

===============================================

Добавлено в 18:40

Я спросил у ребят с стековерфлова, они мне вот такой скриптик показали.

```
function singleClick(e) {
// do something, "this" will be the DOM element
}

function doubleClick(e) {
// do something, "this" will be the DOM element
}

$(selector).click(function(e) {
var that = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    var dblclick = parseInt($(that).data('double'), 10);
    if (dblclick > 0) {
        $(that).data('double', dblclick-1);
    } else {
        singleClick.call(that, e);
    }
}, 300);
}).dblclick(function(e) {
$(this).data('double', 2);
doubleClick.call(this, e);
});
```

Все как один говорят что очень нежелательно вешать click и double-click на один елемент, но мне очень нужно. В общем, он работает, то что я хотел - он делает правильно. Но что вы об этом думаете? Может тут подправить что нужно...
Написал сюда, потому что пока не хочу еще закрывать эту тему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мой вариант:

```
var clickCatcher = {
  t: null,
  n: 0,
  handle: 2, // сколько отлавливать, хоть 15
  callback: function(obj, clicks) { // что делать
    // do something
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#el').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    clickCatcher.n++;
    clearTimeout(clickCatcher.t);
    if (clickCatcher.n == clickCatcher.handle) {
      clickCatcher.callback($(this), clickCatcher.handle)
      clickCatcher.n = 0;
      return false;
    }
    clickCatcher.t = setTimeout(function() { clickCatcher.n = 0; }, 200);
  });
});
```

[Демо тут](http://sh4dow.jino.ru/test44.php)

Теоретически  можно оформить в виде плагина, но стоит учитывать, что стандартное "click" он будет перетирать. Также можно скомбинировать вариант мой и [[@knes](/users/2825/knes)](/users/2825/knes), сделав массив clickCatcher'ов и на каждый клик проверять весь прикрепленный массив. Но это уже сами, мне, если честно, просто лень))

Comment: Ваш обычные клики затирает, мне такое не подходит :)  
но спасибо

Comment: Можно перед последней строкой поставить обработчик, который будет на все клики реагировать)

Comment: а таймер у вас поставить 50мс можно будет вместо 200? работать будет?

Comment: Да, в последней строчке) Мне 200 показались приятнее

Comment: "поставить обработчик, который будет на все клики реагировать" - сюда только это допилить и это то что мне нужно, не подскажите где можно посмотреть пример такого обработчика? или хотябы его структуру в двух словах можете сказать? :) Я уже сам буду думать.

Comment: да просто функция любая же.

    function oneClick() { ... }
    ...
    oneClick();
    clickCatcher.t = setTimeout(function() { clickCatcher.n = 0; }, 200);

Answer (score 2):

В руководстве специально отмечено, что не стоит особо пытаться использовать стандартные функции двойного и одинарного клика: в любом случае, сначала сработает одинарный, а потом двойной, так как с точки зрения браузера двойной - это два отдельных, просто с небольшим интервалом.

Единственный способ проверить - задать интервал между нажатиями, а потом отслеживать два идущих подряд события.

```
var clickCounter = new Array();
$('#here').click(function () {
    clickCounter.push('true');
    setTimeout('clickCounter.pop()', 50);
    if (clickCounter.length > 2) {
        //Двойной,тройной и тд. Можно для всех написать
        clickCounter = new Array(); //обнуляем
    } else {
        //одинарный
        clickCounter = new Array(); //обнуляем. ВНИМАНИЕ!!! БАГ.
    }
});
```

Comment: задать интервал между нажатиями - хм, интересно
это стандартные функции?

Comment: Да, вполне стандартные. Проблема в том, что вы не сможете получить системные значения этих величин.

Comment: Чтото не могу понять как он работает. Использовал ваш пример, вот что firebug выдаёт  

    clickCounter is not defined
    setTimeout('clickCounter.pop()', 50);

создаем массив clickCoutner  
кликаем  
засовываем в массив елемент "true" - это аналог единицы? мол, чтоб не пустой был?  
setTimeout('clickCounter.pop()', 50);  - вот тут не могу сообразить, устанавливаем интервал, через 50 секунд вытянуть из массива последний елемент  
а в следующей строчке проверяем уже сколько в массиве елементов.. ну дальше понятно уже

можете рассказала или дать ссылку на информация о том что здесь происходит

Comment: @knes, я бы еще отменял предыдущий интервал, ибо у вас при 5 кликах по 21ms покажет "3" (2 успеют удалиться). Так что не нужно не `pop()`, а обнуление по таймауту + очистка таймаута по клику, тогда каждый клик будет добавлять по 50ms ожидания.

Comment: Алсо, при первом клике массив все равно обнулится)

Comment: Да, насчет первого клика вы правы. =( Буду думать.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, надо ловить событие:

```
$("#here").click(function(){
    //somethings
});
$("#here").dblclick(function(){
    //somthing
});
```

Comment: в этом случае сработают оба